# Creating plugin for Django-CMS

Tags: database, django, plugins, django-models, django-cms

I think I screwed up somewhere while trying to create a django-cms plugin and now I am unable to go back. The plugin (called sbbplugin) seems to be "working" (it gets displayed) but whenever I try to publish the site I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/cms/page/18/publish/

relation "cmsplugin_sbbmodel" does not exist
LINE 1: ...id", "cmsplugin_sbbmodel"."cmsplugin_ptr_id" FROM "cmsplugin...
                                                             ^
```

I tried removing the plugin but I can not do it because the page is not published. My plugin has no models or anything. Also I'm unable to remove the plugin from the page by clicking delete. Seems like the database is broken.  Since I am not experienced enough to know what information you need I would appreciate it, if you could give me further instructions on what I should do.

Update: I think the problem is that I tried to use a model (sbbmodel) which I deleted. Should I try to add the model again? If so what should I do to fix the database? Do I have to run a migration for my app? Do I even have to register the plugin as an app?

Update2: So I tried to add the model again and migrate the app but I get the following error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
sbbplugin.sbbmodel: Accessor for field 'cmsplugin_ptr' clashes with related field 'CMSPlugin.sbbmodel'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'cmsplugin_ptr'.
sbbplugin.sbbmodel: Reverse query name for field 'cmsplugin_ptr' clashes with related field 'CMSPlugin.sbbmodel'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'cmsplugin_ptr'.
S.sbbmodel: Accessor for field 'cmsplugin_ptr' clashes with related field 'CMSPlugin.sbbmodel'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'cmsplugin_ptr'.
S.sbbmodel: Reverse query name for field 'cmsplugin_ptr' clashes with related field 'CMSPlugin.sbbmodel'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'cmsplugin_ptr'.
```

which I do not really understand because I never specified a foreign key. I assume it is because I inherit from CMSPlugin. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. First I removed every file that I created for my plugin. Then I deleted every instance of my plugin that was saved in the database. Unfortunately that did not solve the problem and I was still getting the same error even after restarting the server.

What did the trick was to go into phpPgAdmin and select all tables than choose "correct". It did not tell me what exactly the issue was but afterwards everything was back to normal again. So if you somehow run into the same problem, just "correct" your database automatically.